Moveit2 with Doosan-Robotics - Error using "rosdep-install" as it can't resolve rosdep keys to system dependencies
Disclaimer:
Week-old beginner in working with Ubuntu and ROS.
Someone asked same doubt at Doosan-Robotics' GitHub too but no response was received.
Goal:
Use the Moveit2 implementation for Doosan-Robotics package.
Specifications:

Ubuntu-20.04 as dual-boot (to avoid virtualization or WSL complications)
ROS2-foxy (EOL at present) successfully installed. ROS1-noetic also installed but I don't think its causing any mix-up complications.
Doosan-Robotics package for ROS2-foxy successfully installed. I was able to connect to the real robot (model M1013) and run an example script.

Issue:
On this link and skipping to the last heading (Moveit), I get an error in the "rosdep-install" part. Here's the error message:

bineetbarman@bineetbarman-IdeaPad-5-15ITL05:~$ source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
ROS_DISTRO was set to 'noetic' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
bineetbarman@bineetbarman-IdeaPad-5-15ITL05:~$ cd ros2_ws
bineetbarman@bineetbarman-IdeaPad-5-15ITL05:~/ros2_ws$ source install/setup.bash
ROS_DISTRO was set to 'foxy' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
ROS_DISTRO was set to 'noetic' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
bineetbarman@bineetbarman-IdeaPad-5-15ITL05:~/ros2_ws$ rosdep update --include-eol-distros
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index-v4.yaml
Add distro "ardent"
Add distro "bouncy"
Add distro "crystal"
Add distro "dashing"
Add distro "eloquent"
Add distro "foxy"
Add distro "galactic"
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "humble"
Add distro "hydro"
Add distro "indigo"
Add distro "iron"
Add distro "jade"
Add distro "jazzy"
Add distro "kinetic"
Add distro "lunar"
Add distro "melodic"
Add distro "noetic"
Add distro "rolling"
updated cache in /home/bineetbarman/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
bineetbarman@bineetbarman-IdeaPad-5-15ITL05:~/ros2_ws$ rosdep install -r --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro foxy -y
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
moveit_kinematics: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rsl]
moveit_resources_prbt_ikfast_manipulator_plugin: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [generate_parameter_library]
pilz_industrial_motion_planner: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [orocos_kdl_vendor]
chomp_motion_planner: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rsl]
moveit_ros_planning: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [generate_parameter_library]
moveit_planners_stomp: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rsl]
moveit_servo: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [generate_parameter_library]
moveit_core: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rsl]
Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
bineetbarman@bineetbarman-IdeaPad-5-15ITL05:~/ros2_ws$ 
 

As expected, "colcon build" gives an error too because the dependencies were not installed yet.
What I've tried till now:

To not forget to source the relevant setup.bash files.
Added the "--include-eol-distros" parameter to not skip "foxy" in rosdep update
Checked official Moveit2 site, foxy wasn't even mentioned. Tried to use this site, but same issue.

If I have to bail:
There is a branch for ROS2 Humble but I'm afraid that's going to be an even bigger headache

As rosdep only looks for "binary installer" (*.deb files on Ubuntu), such an installer must be made available for the package in question.
Looking at https://index.ros.org/search/?term=rsl the rsl package isn't made available (people often call such status as "released"), hence rosdep failed to resolve it.
When an installer isn't available, alternative is to build by yourself. Clone from https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/RSL.
